# Apache Time Issue

Tags: python, django, apache

I currently have a django site that is using cookie sessions. Ive noticed that the session is randomly being logged out. When debugging this I found it was due to the logic within my code looking at the age of the session.
However I then noticed that during the periods that there were no issues the correct time showed in the Apache timestamp. But then the tiemstamp went back 5 hours when then caused my Django program to believe the session had expired and log it out.

Below shows you an example,

```
[Wed Jul 31 16:12:45 2013] [error] DEBUG ok elapsed time 7
[Wed Jul 31 16:12:45 2013] [error] DEBUG ok elapsed time 1
[Wed Jul 31 10:12:46 2013] [error] DEBUG : request.user.is_authenticated()
[Wed Jul 31 10:12:46 2013] [error] DEBUG ok elapsed time 64809
[Wed Jul 31 10:12:46 2013] [error] DEBUG  since begin . elapsedTime.seconds 64809
[Wed Jul 31 10:12:46 2013] [error] DEBUG request.session\\['deginRequest'\\]
[Wed Jul 31 10:12:46 2013] [error] DEBUG ok elapsed time 64801
[Wed Jul 31 10:12:46 2013] [error] DEBUG  since last req . elapsedTime.seconds 64801
[Wed Jul 31 10:12:46 2013] [error] DEBUG request.session\\['lastRequest'\\]
[Wed Jul 31 10:12:47 2013] [error] DEBUG : shouldLogout
```

The issue also randomly happens. Any ideas ?

Also here is the middleware Im using (which generates these logs),

```
class timeOutMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):

        shouldLogout = False

        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            print "DEBUG :request.user.is_authenticated()"
            if 'beginSession' in request.session:
                elapsedTime = datetime.datetime.now() - \
                              request.session['beginSession']
                print "DEBUG ok elapsed time",elapsedTime.seconds
                if elapsedTime.seconds > 12*3600:
                    print "DEBUG  since begin . elapsedTime.seconds",elapsedTime.seconds
                    del request.session['beginSession']
                    print "DEBUG  request.session\[\'deginRequest\'\]"

                    shouldLogout = True
            else:
                request.session['beginSession'] = datetime.datetime.now()

            if 'lastRequest' in request.session:
                elapsedTime = datetime.datetime.now() - \
                              request.session['lastRequest']
                print "DEBUG ok elapsed time",elapsedTime.seconds
                if elapsedTime.seconds > 2*3600:
                    print "DEBUG   since last req . elapsedTime.seconds",elapsedTime.seconds
                    del request.session['lastRequest']
                    shouldLogout = True

            request.session['lastRequest'] = datetime.datetime.now()


            username = request.user
            if ####.objects.get(username=username).token:
                print "DEBUG : ####.objects.get(username=username).token"

                try:
                    token = ####.objects.get(username=username).token
                    url = 'https://############/%s' % (token)
                    response = requests.get(url)
                    answer = json.loads(response.text)
                    #print "DEBUG answer",answer
                    if not answer["valid"]:
                        shouldLogout = True
                        print "DEBUG",datetime.now(),"not answer[\"valid\"]"
                except:
                    shouldLogout = True
                    print "DEBUG except"
            else:
                shouldLogout = True
                print "DEBUG else"

            if shouldLogout:
                print "DEBUG : ",datetime.datetime.now(),"shouldLogout"
                logout(request)

        else:
            if 'beginSession' in request.session:
                del request.session['beginSession']
            if 'lastRequest' in request.session:
                del request.session['lastRequest']

        return None
```

Comment: Are you looking for the age in order to expire the session? If yes, you should avoid it, there is the SESSION_COOKIE_AGE setting for this purpose. You might want to have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age

Comment: I have logic on this but there is other logic that I require based on the time.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by Apache timestamp? Do you mean the timestamps logged in the acccess log?
If so, can you provide sample log lines and the mod_log_config configuration?

Comment: it seems a machine misconfiguration. Are you sure your ntp is right configured on your server.

Comment: Yes NTP is configured. Though it appears to going back 5 hours each time which seems more like a timezone maybe ...

Comment: Can you show us corresponding code for messages in the question? Want to know how you are getting age, expiry etc.

Comment: Is this running on a virtual machine? Is there anything in the system logs around the time went forward? How often is the time jumping? Is the time correct immediately after a reboot?

Comment: Is this hosted using wsgi and are there other applications on the same server also hosted by wsgi?

Comment: Yes im using wgsi, across 2 virtual environments.

Comment: Ive noticed that the other environment had the wrong timezone. Just testing...

Comment: What is 'other environment'? The VMW host ?

Comment: The other django project/virtual environment ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache logs indicate a very discrete time step of 5 hours so this is unlikely to be an underlying system time adjustment by a time keeping daemon such as ntp.  I'd guess that it's almost certain to be related to a timezone setting.

If you're using mod_wsgi to serve your app in non-daemon mode, there could be shared state between processes from the environment.  In particular, you should take note of the information in the following link: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Timezone_and_Locale_Settings

As suggested in other answers, it's a good idea to always store time in UTC and only convert to a specific time zone up presentation.

Consider running your application in wsgi daemon mode.  From the [mod_wsgi docs](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)

> Although embedded mode can technically perform better, daemon mode
>   would generally be the safest choice to use.

Daemon mode ensure that you have an isolated process handling your application with no possibility for environment contamination from other wsgi processes. eg TZ environment variable changes.

Comment: Thanks, Im still testing this so will let you know and award the points accordingly. Its still interesting though that the webframework (in this case python/django) can overwrite the system/apache timezone.

Comment: Looks like this has resolved the issue. Note : There were 2 problems here, other environments configured as embedded, and also some of the other environments (there were more then 2 in the end :o) had the wrong time zone. Thanks again for the help....

Comment: Looks like i awarded the points slighty early. After 3 days of testing no issues. As soon as I awarded the points the issue has recurred !!

Comment: @felix001 Can you please add your wsgi setup to the question, it may provide further clues.  Also, post the Django `TIME_ZONE` setting for each app, and the time zone of /etc/localtime.  Also see Graham's answer (author of mod_wsgi).  You can unaccept this answer since it doesn't appear to solve your problem.

Comment: To be honest the more im looking at this now the more issues Im seeing. Ive also just found a ruby on rails app with the wrong timezones. this have been changed and im testing and all looks fine. plus with the changes to django to just use utc all looks good. So both yours and Rohans answers helped :o)

Answer (score 2):

This seems an OS/HW misconfiguration.

I suspect that some times your network fails and OS (Operating Sistem) need to get data from hardware clock but ntp.

You should ensure than **BIOS clock UTC configuration match with `/etc/default/rcS` parameters**:

```
# assume that the BIOS clock is set to UTC time (recommended)
UTC=no
```

Also, ensure your timezone configuration is right:

```
root@egg-v3:/etc# cat /etc/timezone 
Europe/Barcelona
```

Some easy tests:

- start machine without ntp. If system data is not right, try it changing `UTC` parameter.
- Play with `hwclock` command:

Sample:

```
root@egg-v3:/etc# hwclock 
Fri 02 Aug 2013 04:30:54 PM CEST  -0.609670 seconds
root@egg-v3:/etc# date
Fri Aug  2 14:30:55 CEST 2013
```

Comment: Thanks, though this is a VM. Also ntp has been disabled and VMtools installed to sync the time from the hypervisor.

Comment: This raises the entropy! Anyway, check virtual hw time catch with /etc/default/rcS file.

Comment: Your VM is not getting its clock sync'd correctly. Either vmtools is not working correctly (often happens with linux vm), or your HW clock is not adjusted correctly.  Use a NTP server from your network or the Internet to adjust the clock accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve your issue, but worth suggesting. And putting that in comment doesn't look appropriate.

---

Use timezone aware datetime objects instead of naive objects (`datetime.datetime.now()` gives you that.)

And use `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` rather than `.now()` when working with date/times.

So from [django timezones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/)

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

It might be case that when django applying timezones when converting time stored in `request.session['beginSession']` from naive to timezone aware objects incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, and this is a great response. However doesn't it suggest that theres an issue at the system time level as the time shows incorrectly in the Apache logs.

Comment: @felix001, I would suspect that is caused by some ntp config or timezone settings on machine. Can you check if this happens at particular time/day or specific interval? Also use `elapsedTime.total_seconds()` to get difference in seconds rather than `elapsedTime.seconds`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it resolved the issue even though i can still see it happening. i.e the apache logs show the wrong time but the app works as its not using timezones. Thanks,

Comment: @felix001, you have 2 problems. 1. time in django app, that can be solved by method I described. 2. Apache log timing - which is mostly some ntp issue or some other process messing with timezone setting on system or apache env. Commonly seen if multiple sites are served on same instance. If you haven't already looked http://serverfault.com/questions/26248/what-could-cause-apaches-time-timezone-to-change-intermittently

Comment: To be honest the more im looking at this now the more issues Im seeing. Ive also just found a ruby on rails app with the wrong timezones. this have been changed and im testing and all looks fine. plus with the changes to django to just use utc all looks good. So both yours and Austin Phillips answers helped :o)

Answer (score 0):

The difference in time stamps in the log file is usually because your system time zone is different to what Django has been configured to use. If using embedded mode of Apache/mod_wsgi you can also have problems where you are also hosting PHP applications on the same Apache server and PHP is using a different time zone.